# Create a child class's instance in parent class's method

Tags: scala, inheritance

```
abstract class Parent {
   def filter(p: Parent => Boolean): Parent = filterAcc(p, new Child)
}

class Child extends Parent {
  // ...
}
```

I am working on Scala tutorial and wondering how the following can be possible.

There are two classes `Parent` and `Child`.  The `Parent` class creates an instance of `child` in the method `filter`.

How can a parent class refer to a child class which inherits the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

That is no contradiction. If parent and child are defined within the same compilation unit, then the parent can refer to its sub-class, both symbols/types are known to each other.